# Form Layout with Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to layout a form with Bootstrap 3. My form is broken down into groups. For example, my form looks like this:

```
[h4]Personal Info[/h4]
First Name  [text field   ]
Last Name   [text field   ]
Birthday    [date field   ]

[h4]Contact Info[/h4]
Email Address  [text field   ]
Phone Number   [text field   ]
```

In an attempt to create this form, I have the following code:

```
<h4>Personal Info</h4>
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="FirstName">First Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="firstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="">
</div>
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="LastName">Last Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="lastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="">
</div>
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="Birthday">Birthday</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="Birthday" name="Birthday" type="text" value="">
</div>

<h4>Contact Info</h4>
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="EmailAddress">Email Address</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="emailAddress" name="EmailAddress" type="text" value="">
</div>

<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="PhoneNumber">Phone number</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="phoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

When I run this code, my form has several problems:
1. There is not padding or margin between the groups.
2. The labels are not left aligned. In addition, they are verically aligned against the bottom of the row instead of vertically centered with the input field.

Unfortunately, I suck at CSS. I thought I Bootstrap would help me tackle these scenarios. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use class `form-group` and `form` for better alignment in bootstrap form components and `form-control` class

like this

```
<div class="container">
<form class="form-horizontal">
<h4>Personal Info</h4>  
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="FirstName">First Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="firstName" name="FirstName" type="text" value="">
</div>
  </div>
<div class="form-group">  
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="LastName">Last Name</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="lastName" name="LastName" type="text" value="">
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="Birthday">Birthday</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="Birthday" name="Birthday" type="text" value="">
</div>
  </div>

<h4>Contact Info</h4>
  <div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="EmailAddress">Email Address</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="emailAddress" name="EmailAddress" type="text" value="">
</div>
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-4 control-label" for="PhoneNumber">Phone number</label>
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <input class="form-control input-sm" id="phoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" type="text" value="">
</div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

[**Bootply DEMO**](http://www.bootply.com/FPT1tqYIR2)

please read the [**bootstrap form documentation**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)

Comment: there ya go. the first sample was very broken.

Comment: @SajadKaruthedath - This is close. However, the labels and fields aren't left-aligned. So it looks incredibly awkward. At the same time, there is no vertical space between "Contact Info" and the "Birthday" field. How do I make those two things happen?

Answer (score 0):

See the docs on horizontal forms:

[**Bootstrap Horizontal Form Docs**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

You just need to adjust your markup.

It should be along these lines:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Edited to add a [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b15nwLck/embedded/result/)